# How to get user email of delegated calendar with Office.js API when running Outlook COM Add-in (in native Outlook on Windows)?

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am developing an Outlook Web Add-in and run it in the native Outlook 2019 on Windows. My colleague delegates me his calendar and I have an access to his calendar and can run my web Add-in in shared calendar's Appointment. I'm using F12 Developer Tools to see console logs. So, the main problem for me - to get a shared calendar's user email. I tried to get `Office.context.mailbox.item.organizer` but in console of F12 DevTools I see `undefined`. When I try to get `Office.context.mailbox.item` in console of F12 Devtools I see `[object] { }` and I don't know how to see all object properties.

In `manifest.xml` of my Add-in I added `<SupportsSharedFolders>true</SupportsSharedFolders>`, but it doesn't help me (I think it is only needed when I can't see my Add-in in the ribbon, but I already saw it without this parameter line).

Also I tried to change permissions in `manifest.xml` from "ReadWriteItem" to "ReadWriteMailbox
" - no changes.

I looked at the official Microsoft documentation and there I read that I can call `Office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync` and pass as callback function with param `asyncResult0` wherein I call `Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync` ([link to official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.mailbox?view=outlook-js-1.1&preserve-view=true#getCallbackTokenAsync_callback__userContext_)), and `saveAsync` is called without problems (except that I can't access `asyncResult0.value` field of `asyncResult0` and can't actually see what fields there are in console because of F12 Devtools), but further in console of F12 Devtools I see `Object doesn't support property or method 'getCallbackTokenAsync', TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'getCallbackTokenAsync'`. If this method were called I would do the following:

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync(function (asyncResult0) {
  Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync({
      isRest: true
    },
    function (asyncResult) {
      if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded && asyncResult.value !== "") {
        Office.context.mailbox.item.getSharedPropertiesAsync({
            // Pass auth token along.
            asyncContext: asyncResult.value
          },
          function (asyncResult1) {
            const sharedProperties = asyncResult1.value; // may be it contains shared calendar user email
            // some operations...
          }
        );
      }
    }
  );
});
```

**Important details:**

1. In `manifest.xml`:

- Requirement set MinVersion 1.1
- Requirement set DefaultMinVersion 1.3
- And also I don't know am I using Microsoft documentation correctly.

2. I created a draft of Appointment in shared calendar and tried everything described above in this draft.
3. I don't know how to debug more correctly COM Add-in (Web version based) and now I know only about F12 Devtools.
4. I don't know is it important, but just in case I write that when I run my Add-in in Office 365 *(only in Appointment of my calendar, because Add-in is not installing with `<SupportsSharedFolders>true</SupportsSharedFolders>` in Office 365 and without it I can't see Add-in in shared calendar)* I can see all properties of `Office.context.mailbox.item` object in console. `Office.context.mailbox.item.organizer` returns object with method `getAsync` which if I call (and pass as callback function with `result` param) I get the `result`: `{ status: "succeeded", value: { displayName: "...", emailAddress: "..." } }` (in this case with data of my user of course). And also I was able to get `asyncResult0` in callback passed to `saveAsync`, and also `asyncResult` in callback passed to `getCallbackTokenAsync`. But when calling `getSharedPropertiesAsync` in console I see "Office.context.mailbox.item.getSharedPropertiesAsync is not a function".
5. In native Outlook Add-in is using `Office = window.external` object as Office JS API point.
6. `Office.context.mailbox.diagnostics.hostVersion` in console shows: **16.0.0.10368**

Help me please. I have no ideas how to get user email of shared calendar in Appointment with Office.js API. I will be glad to any leads.

Best Regards!

Answer (score 1):

In a shared calendar/folder, you can only obtain the email address of the owner by calling [Office.context.mailbox.item.getSharedPropertiesAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.8/outlook-requirement-set-1.8). In your own calendar/folder (non-shared), the `getSharedPropertiesAsync` API does not exist because you can simply call `Office.context.mailbox.item.organizer` to get the email address of the owner of the appointment/meeting.

Comment: I tried to call `Office.context.mailbox.item.getSharedPropertiesAsync`, but in console I see `Object doesn't support property or method 'getSharedPropertiesAsync', TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'getSharedPropertiesAsync'`. May be with the Office.js version 16.0 it needs to be done somehow differently?

Comment: `getSharedPropertiesAsync` was added in requirement set 1.8 : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.8/outlook-requirement-set-1.8

Since you are using build 16.0.0.10368, you don't have a version of Outlook that supports 1.8. You can check by calling : Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported("Mailbox", "1.8"). You should only use the APIs in 1.8 if the output of this call is true.
Consider upgrading your Office installation to a more recent version so that you can use this API.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I checked what you suggested and when I called `console.log(Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported("Mailbox", "1.8"))`, I saw `true` result in console. Also I checked new updates on my Office and there are nothing, all is up to date.

Comment: What version of Exchange are you using? Also, in your manifest, what requirement set did you specify for Mailbox?